# Runtime Warnings on multiplication of NumPy FFT

Tags: python, numpy, fft

I am trying to follow [this](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/736/how-do-i-implement-cross-correlation-to-prove-two-audio-files-are-similar/739#739?newreg=f069471075a54b39852dd5738e5ad77e) method of comparing .wav files, but am getting the following warnings:

```
valid:call.py:23: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in multiply
  mult = numpy.multiply(fft1, fft2)
call.py:23: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in multiply
  mult = numpy.multiply(fft1, fft2)
```

I examine what's happening and find that `mult` is set to the following:

```
[[ inf -0.j  nan-infj  nan+infj ...,  nan+infj  nan-infj  nan+infj]
 [ inf -0.j -inf+nanj  inf+nanj ..., -inf+nanj  inf+nanj -inf+nanj]
 [ inf -0.j  nan-infj  inf+nanj ...,  nan-infj  inf+nanj  nan+infj]
 ..., 
 [ inf -0.j -inf+nanj -inf+nanj ..., -inf+nanj -inf+nanj -inf+nanj]
 [ inf -0.j -inf+nanj -inf+nanj ..., -inf+nanj -inf+nanj -inf+nanj]
 [ inf -0.j  nan-infj  nan-infj ...,  nan+infj  nan+infj  nan+infj]]
```

As instructed by the answer on dsp.stackexchange, I am zero-padding my data.  Is this causing infinities?  How can I multiply a list of complex values?

**UPDATE:**  I have changed it to "manually" multiply like so:

```
mult = [i*j for (i, j) in itertools.izip(fft1, fft2)]
```

and am getting fewer `nan-inf`s, but still a few.  It now is producing the following warnings:

```
valid:call.py:26: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in cdouble_scalars
  mult = [i*j for (i, j) in itertools.izip(a, b)]
call.py:26: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in cdouble_scalars
  mult = [i*j for (i, j) in itertools.izip(a, b)]
```

but it seems to be closer.  Any thoughts?

**UPDATE 2**
Of course I had forgotten the kluge way I'm unpacking the wav chunks.  I did a `sys.getsizeof(frames[0])` to find that the size of each element is 36.  Code here:

```
def get_fft(fft_path):
    return_list = []
    frames_list = []
    chunk_size = 36
    start = 0
    wav = wave.open(fft_path, 'r')
    frames = wav.readframes(wav.getnframes())
    wav.close()

    while start+chunk_size < len(frames):
            data = struct.unpack(">fdddd", frames[start:start+chunk_size])
            frames_list.extend(data)
            start += chunk_size
            if len(frames_list) >= 1000:
                    frames_list.extend(numpy.zeros(len(frames_list)))
                    return_list.append(numpy.fft.fft(frames_list))
                    frames_list = []

    return return_list
```

The problem most likely lie here: `data = struct.unpack(">fdddd", frames[start:start+chunk_size])`.  The string `">fdddd"` tells unpack to "get" little endian (`>`) a four-byte float (`f`) and four eight-byte doubles (`d`).  I most likely am misunderstanding the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html).

Comment: Are you sure you are converting the data from the WAV correctly. Secondly, why do you want to deal with nan/inf, why not just use a larger data type.

Comment: What is current datatype of your array?  Just use a larger-one (e.g. `complex128` or `complex256` ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**OP Solution:** As @rth and @Claris guess I was unpacking my data incorrectly.  Running `sys.getsizeof()` on the elements of `frames` led me to believe that each element had to be unpacked in 36-byte chunks.

As indicated in another answer (which I lost ): ), I had to unpack the frames in smaller chunks:

```
data = struct.unpack(">fdddd", frames[start:start+chunk_size])
```

I changed to:

```
data = struct.unpack(">H", frames[start:start+chunk_size])
```

And I changed `chunk_size` from 36 to 2.  The element-wise multiplication is working fine now, no `NaN`s or `Inf`s.

See more on [struct.unpack()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html).